# help please answer the question regarding regression model analysis?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, model

[![regression model.][1]][1]

[solve the questions given here.]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2LHc.png

Answer (score 1):

I will provide you hints with as much effort as you've provided asking the question

A)  What kind of dependent variable do you have?  What kind of dependent variable does the model in a) imply?

B) Take appropriate limits and compute the derivative.  If a function is monotonically increasing, what do we know about it's derivative?

C) What do you know of these three measures?

D) What do you know of these two measures

E) What do you know of these two measures